# d3 enter().append() not appending all elements of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm working on my first mid-scale d3 project right now after having run through the tutorials. I understand scales, enter, update, and exit, so I'm pretty confused about a problem I'm running into.

I have an array of JSON objects with two fields, `year` and `number`. I am creating a bar chart with this array with the following code:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll('g')
    .data(yearData)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      console.log(i);
      return 'translate(' + i * barWidth + ',0)'; });
```

My confusion stems from the fact that the `console.log` statement in this code block outputs `27` as its first value. In other words, d3 is skipping elements 0 - 26 of my array. Why could this be??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because you already have `g` elements on your page (e.g. from adding an axis). These are selected and matched with data, so the enter selection doesn't contain everything you expect.

One solution is to assign a class to these elements and select accordingly:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll('g.bar')
 .data(yearData)
 .enter().append('g')
 .attr("class", "bar")
 // ...
```

Much more detail on this in the second half of [this tutorial](http://www.airpair.com/d3.js/getting-started-tutorial).

Comment: Thank you Lars, you hit the nail on the head. - Ian

Comment: You rock Lars. Saved my day